# R function for repeat loop to create multiple variables from table

Tags: r, loops

Apologies for any poorly formed question - I'm very new to R.

I am looking to create multiple character strings from this [data table](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KHC966YRwqW1lkuwmGYoT8mPUYNcSJRU)..

I have created the character string:
coor1 <-  R_data[1,8]

I am looking to iterate this for other indices as follows:

```
coor1 <- data[1,8]
coor2 <- data[2,8]
coor3 <- data[3,8]
coor4 <- data[4,8]
coor5 <- data[5,8] etc....
```

I have tried using a for loop but with no success. Any advice would be great.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please provide a [mcve]. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248) for what this would mean in R.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to subset the 8th column with `$`:

```
data <- data.frame(V1 = rep(NA, 26))
data[, 2:7] <- NA
data[, 8] <- letters

data$V8
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u"
[22] "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"

data[1, 8]
[1] "a"

data[2, 8]
[1] "b"

data[3, 8]
[1] "c"

data[4, 8]
[1] "d"
```

You can assign it to a variable as well:

```
coor <- data$V8
```

And extract a single result with `[]`:

```
coor[1]
[1]"a"

coor[2]
[1] "b"
```

This can also be accomplished from the original dataframe:

```
data$V8[1]
[1] "a"
```

which is same as:

```
data[1, 8]
[1] "a"
```

What a loop would look like:

```
coors <- vector() #allocate space for storage
for(i in seq_len(nrow(data))){
  coors[i] <- data[i, 8]
}
```